# What is the default value of the AesManaged.KeySize property?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

It seems that the documentation of the [`AesManaged.KeySize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.keysize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is lacking the default value. There is a statement about the maximum key size:

> The maximum size of the key is 256 bits.

in the remarks. But since the AES algorithm is able to handle keys of 128, 192 or 256 bit, the actual default may not be 256. So...what is it?

Comment: 256 https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhxU7l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `AesManaged.KeySize` will return 256 by default, at least for .NET version 4.5.

Comment: what about the new `Aes` class?

Comment: It will depend on the underlying class, but I would therefore strongly suspect a value of 256 (bits), as `AesManaged` is one of them. I wish that Microsoft would document these kind of things.